# RestDocumentation Class Spring

Tags: spring-restdocs

Spring org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation class override apply method of org.junit.rules.TestRule which implies that all test cases should be written in Junit. How can i achieve the same functionality using TestNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not built-in support for using TestNG at the moment. You might be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/171) which is tracking the possibility of adding it.